# How to find how much of a circle hangs out of a rectangle

Tags: python, math, coordinates, shapes

What is the area of this circle that hangs out of the rectangle (imagine the rectangle stretches out to (infinity, infinity) on both ends), and how can I generalize this to any circle of any radius as well as any rectangle of any dimensions.

[image: Circle of radius 7, origin at (3,2), partly hanging out of a rectangle that has a corner at (0,0), stretching out infinitely in both positive directions1]

I have a coding problem in which I need to calculate what percentage of the circle is in the rectangle for a number of different circles, I am struggling with the code when the corner of the rectangle is covered. Without the corner issue, I could simply see how far away each protruding edge is, then use some circle/trig math to find the area of each outside bit. But once the corner is covered, the code overcounts the corner bit: in the extreme case where the circle is at (0,0) it counts the left half as out and the top half as out, and concludes that the whole circle is out. I've drawn diagrams but I've failed to find a way to discover the overcounted area. I originally tried finding the dimensions of the outer triangle, but I can't figure out that either.

I know there is an answer, because there's enough information for only one possibility, but I can't figure out how.

This is the code I have so far, it just counts how much area that the segments perpendicular to the axes cover, thus overcounts when these segments overlap.
xbounds is a tuple (low, high) for the width of the rectangle and ybounds[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bT9qU.png) (low, high) is a tuple for the height of the rectangle these just say where the rectangle starts and ends on the x and y axes, in practice, the first value is 0 because the rectangle starts at zero and the second values are very large numbers.
Range is the radius of the circle.
Pos is an imaginary number representing the origin where real is the x coord and imag is the y coord.

```
r2 = range*range
outarea = 0
        
if (b:= -pos.real+range+xbounds[0])>0:
    theta = 2*acos(1-b/range)
    outarea=0.5*r2*(theta-sin(theta))
        
if (b:= pos.real+range-xbounds[1])>0:
    theta = 2*acos(1-b/range)
    outarea+=0.5*r2*(theta-sin(theta))
        
if (b:= -pos.imag+range+ybounds[0])>0:
    theta = 2*acos(1-b/range)
    outarea+=0.5*r2*(theta-sin(theta))
        
if (b:= pos.imag+range-ybounds[1])>0:
    theta = 2*acos(1-b/range)
    outarea+=0.5*r2*(theta-sin(theta))
```

Comment: This is a math problem, not a programming problem.

Comment: I considered posting on mathoverflow, but all the posts i saw there were highly theoretical and abstract, which made my geometry problem feel out of place. I felt that this forum was better suited for trying to find a good answer, as i was looking for a python code snippet i could use to compute the area.

Comment: Mathoverflow is not appropriate, that's true, but there is also https://math.stackexchange.com/. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41/differences-between-mathoverflow-and-math-stackexchange#:~:text=The%20distinction%20will%20probably%20be,once%20the%20site%20goes%20public.&text=MathOverflow%20is%20for%20research%20level,since%20those%20are%20at%20MO).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the corner (I'll call it O) is in the interior of the circle, you can

- Draw a line between the two intersections A and B.
- Get the area of the right triangle ABO (green below).
- Get the area of the sector between A and B, centered at the center of the circle C (yellow plus blue below). This should just be `pi*r*r*percentage`, where `percentage` can be computed using the formula theta = arccos((CA dot product CB) / (|CA| |CB|)), then `percentage = theta / twopi`.
- Compute the area of the triangle ABC (blue below). Might need Heron's formula.
- The area (yellow below) between the chord AB and the circle is Area(sector) - Area(triangle ABC).
- The area of the intersection of the circle and the rectangle is (Area between chord and circle) + Area(triangle ABC). This is Green plus yellow below.
- The area of circle outside of the rectangle is the area of the circle minus their intersection.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, especially for including little code snippets, i cant believe i had been looking at the wrong place (outside) the whole time, this is a really clever solution!